# How to initialize MutableList with default values using a variable?

Tags: scala, list, variables, fill, mutable

Class List contains such method called "fill", but I couldn't find any similar method in MutableList class.

```
var fields: MutableList[MutableList[Boolean]] = new MutableList.fill(size, size)(true)
```

^ doesn't work

Comment: You don't need `new` keyword. `fill` is a method in `MutableList`'s [**companion object**](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.x/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.MutableList$) (you can click blue O letter to go to the class docs and vice versa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`fill`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/MutableList$.html#fill[A](n1:Int,n2:Int)(elem:=>A):CC[CC[A]]) is a method on the companion object of `MutableList` (similar to how it's defined on `List`s companion). This works:

```
val fields: MutableList[MutableList[Boolean]] = MutableList.fill(size, size)(true)
```

---

```
scala> val fields: MutableList[MutableList[Boolean]] = MutableList.fill(2, 2)(true)
fields: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[Boolean]] = MutableList(MutableList(true, true), MutableList(true, true))
```